# How to check whether a usb Wifi supports Hotspot or not

Tags: linux, wifi

I found a wifi card here:-

[Wifi](http://www.amazon.in/COMFAST-CF-WU715N-150Mbps-wireless-adapter/dp/B00C3F5C1C/ref=pd_cp_pc_1)

Now, how can I check whether It can enter master mode and have support for hotspot? As my current in-built Wifi card is giving me this:-

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

On executing:-

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
```

I am seeing `SoftAP` in its heading. Should I assume that I will go in master mode on my linux box?